# Tail won't add when colliding on a food in snake game in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a snake game, I added a FOOD PREFAB which spawns every 3 seconds, but it doesn't destroy itself and add tail on the head when collided.
I have this code for the HEAD, I think this is where my problem lies.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class SNAKE : MonoBehaviour {

    // Did the snake eat something?
    bool ate = false;
    // Tail Prefab
    public GameObject TAIL_PREFAB;
    // Current Movement Direction
    // (by default it moves to the right)
    Vector2 dir = Vector2.right;
    // Keep Track of Tail
    List<Transform> tail = new List<Transform>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        // Move the Snake every 300ms
        InvokeRepeating("Move", 0.2f, 0.2f);    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    // Update is called once per Frame
    void Update() {
        // Move in a new Direction?
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            dir = Vector2.right;
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            dir = -Vector2.up;    // '-up' means 'down'
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            dir = -Vector2.right; // '-right' means 'left'
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            dir = Vector2.up;
    }



    void Move() {
        // Save current position (gap will be here)
        Vector2 v = transform.position;

        // Move head into new direction (now there is a gap)
        transform.Translate(dir);

        // Ate something? Then insert new Element into gap
        if (ate) {
            // Load Prefab into the world
            GameObject g =(GameObject)Instantiate(TAIL_PREFAB,v,Quaternion.identity);

            // Keep track of it in our tail list
            tail.Insert(0, g.transform);

            // Reset the flag
            ate = false;
        }
        // Do we have a Tail?
        else if (tail.Count > 0) {
            // Move last Tail Element to where the Head was
            tail.Last().position = v;

            // Add to front of list, remove from the back
            tail.Insert(0, tail.Last());
            tail.RemoveAt(tail.Count-1);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll) {
        // Food?
        if (coll.name.StartsWith("FOOD")) {
            // Get longer in next Move call
            ate = true;

            // Remove the Food
            Destroy(coll.gameObject);
        }
        // Collided with Tail or Border
        else {
            // ToDo 'You lose' screen
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add a rigidbody to you prefab?

Comment: I added a rigidbody2d to the food, it now works. But it shows and ERROR
" The Variable TAIL_PREFAB in SNAKE has not been assigned "

Comment: Great, that is because you now have your ate var set true, remember to add a TAIL_PREFAB from the Unity Inspector, just drag and drop a prefab on that field on the Inspector

Comment: Dude, you're incredibly awesome! I wan't to repay you for this. But I don't know how.

Comment: Additional Question, how can I disable the LEFT control if the snake is facing RIGHT, disable UP when facing DOWN vice versa?

Comment: I added the answer, about the second question: you can use your `dir` var and ask if for the direction if !dir.left && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) then set snake to turn to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a rigidbody2d to the food, that should do the job.

See more [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html)

Happy coding!